# How can I update a property in xml binding?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I want to use a way of bindings like this:

```
<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/play"
  android:layout_width="30dp"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:background="@{play.isEnabled() ? @drawable/round_button : @drawable/round_disable_button}"
  android:src="@drawable/play" />
```

I want that binding get updated when I disable or enable that `ImageView` in `Java` class, how can I do this?

Comment: use [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) that has two different drawables for each state

Comment: for more on StateList refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**

Practically, you can create a custom view, extended from `ImageView`, and do this pragmatically.

Edit: you can use MVVM third party library for android like this: https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm